# How can I assign a color to a constant in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public static partial class Const
{

    public static class IconColors
    {
        public const Color  IconBlue1 = Color.FromHex("007AFF");
    }

}
```

But it gives me an error saying that the type Color cannot be declared const.

Does anyone have any suggestions / advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define it like following

```
public class IconColors
{
        public static Color IconBlue1 { get; } = Color.FromHex("007AFF");
}
```

And access it like

```
var color = IconColors.IconBlue1;
```